# make google show two different websites depending on searcher's language

Tags: sitemap, seo

Hi i made a google web master tool account and sent 2 site maps: one for the italian language and one for the english one of my site.
Now, my site has a script in the index that redirects the users to mywebsite.it/it if he's italian otherwise it will go to mywebsite.it/en.
The problem is that now google's crawler(that obviously is not italian) only sees the english version of site and not both of them.

Is there a way to make it crawl and show the two different websites depending on the language?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use JavaScript to redirect the people? It would be better to use a server-side redirect, for example with **.htaccess**

However, when you link both language versions from your index page and Google accepted your sitemaps, your site should be okay to be indexed. Maybe it takes some more time until the crawler visits your Italian site, too.

---

Update: You could/should add a language switcher for users to your site, and also link the translations in the `head` area of your site with the `link` element and `rel="alternate` and `hreflang="it` resp. `"en"`. See [Google: rel="alternate" hreflang="x"](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189077)

Comment: i redirect using a php script inside the main index.php that redirects to site.it/it/index or site.it/en/index depending on the language. Going to google webmaster tools' sitemap section i can see both sitemaps and both are sent and indexed but still if you look for "eurocongressi" on google(even from italy) it shows the english version.

Comment: So your site is eurocongressi.it? [Google indexed](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Aeurocongressi.it) both language version. Which language version is the first result depends on Googles ranking mechanism and the (assumed) language and/or location of the searcher. -- I couldn't find a language switcher on your site, is it missing? Also, you could add `link` element with `rel="alternate"` and `hreflang` to link to the corresponding translation of your pages (see link in my edited answer).

Comment: Thanks, i added that code and will add the language switcher soon.
May i ask you something more? Google webmaster tools says that the most indexed word is "conferences" because it finds it in almost any section of the website. I need to index "Palermo"(my city) at the same level but can't add it to the pages without a real reason.
Does it work if i add it on the page and remove it with css?(with text-indent: -9999px;)

Comment: @g0dl3ss: You shouldn't do that. Google knows about those tricks and might penalize you (from "nothing happens" over "lower ranking" to "total block", everything could happen).